# Calculating Rotations to change carousel face

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, rotations

I am trying to remember how to do something I believe should be quite simple.

I have a slot machine or a carousel, let's focus on one ring. Each ring has five faces, I calculated that each angle is 72deg.

I made a map of each face to the degree it is on the carousel.

```
    const slotMap = {
      0: 288,
      1: 216,
      2: 144,
      3: 72,
      4: 360
  };
```

My problem is when I have a first rotation everything works fine. I just rotate it to the face I need. For example, if it's `face 3` then I rotate by `72deg`.

My issue is trying to find an equation that will turn it to the next face. 
If I have `face 3` and I want it to `face 2`.

I tried by subtracting the difference in the number of faces from the previous face and the current face and multiplying by `72deg` but this did not work.

I believe this has to be either trigonometry or something basic, but it has been bugging me for a long time.

my original equation:

```
| currentFace - previousFace | * 72deg = nextFace
```

has not worked out at all.

I must be forgetting something very basic.

(I am doing this in Javascript but I really want to understand the math before the code)

Comment: Do you remember how to do clock (modular) arithmetic?

Comment: @amd not really, I do know modulus. but I need to be able to convert into degrees to rotate and it needs to be based on the previous face.

Comment: Also, does the ring turn in only one direction, or can you rotate it in either direction to get to the target?

Comment: I was able to get it working in my code. below she solved it in math. but in reality, the 3D object always starts from origin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation works when you try to go from a smaller numbered face to a larger numbered face (from 2 to 3), but not when going from a larger numbered face to a smaller numbered face (from 3 to 2). This is because the equation doesn't distinguish between the two.

For example:

If you want to go from face 2 to face 3:
$\mid 3-2\mid \times 72=72$ (the correct degree value for face 3)

But, when you try to go from face 2 to 3:
$\mid 3-2\mid=\mid 2-3\mid$, so you will get $72$ again.

If you can reassign the degree values for the faces, such that:

```
const slotMap = {
      0: 360,
      1: 288,
      2: 216,
      3: 144,
      4: 72
  };
```

You can make the equation:
`( currentFace - nextFace ) * 72deg` which gives you the degrees you need to rotate.

For example:

To go from face 4 to face 1, you have:

$(4-1) \times 72=216$, which is correct since you need to go $+216^\circ$ from face 4 to get to face 1 ($72^\circ$ to $288^\circ$).

On the other hand, to go from face 1 to 4 you have:

$(1-4) \times 72=-216$, which also holds true.

Comment: ahh makes sense! what would be the right equation here? negative degrees would make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood the equation. Do you want the equation to give you the degree value you need to rotate to get to a new face (-216 degrees from face 0 to 3) or the degree value for the new face (72 for face 3)?

Comment: I need to get the degrees needed to rotate to the new face.

Comment: I cannot reassign the degrees either. I don't have a ton of control over what order the faces are rendered.

Comment: The solution I posted would still work, as long as face 4 could be recognized as both 360 degrees and 0 degrees in your system.

Comment: this is not working sadly. I was able to change the slot map to: `const slotMap = {
      0: 0,
      1: 72,
      2: 144,
      3: 216,
      4: 288
  };`

Comment: solved it! using your equations the math was right but sadly my code shows the object is always starting from an origin! I will accept your answer as I would not have solved it with the equations showing me the proper rotations!